# Loading image in div every second

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to load a image in a div at regular interval, say every second or two

I did some silly attempts like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout('LoadImages()',100 );
});
function LoadImages()
{
   $('#Images').load('get_image.htm'); // get_image.htm displays image
}
</script>
<body>
<div id="Images"><div>
```

I know its all wrong, but what needs to be done to get this working ?

Comment: Have you checked w3schools or any other online tutorials?

Comment: It would be great if people stopped posting w3fools every time someone mentions w3schools, *unless* someone actually links to a problem article on w3schools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   function LoadImages() {

     setTimeout(function() {
        $('#Images').load('get_image.htm'); // get_image.htm displays image
        LoadImages(); // recursive call to LoadImages
     }, 1000)

   }
});
```

if you want to call `LoadImages()` after finish image load then

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   function LoadImages() {

     setTimeout(function() {
        $('#Images').load('get_image.htm', function() {

             LoadImages(); // recursive call to LoadImages

       }); // get_image.htm displays image

     }, 1000)

   }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`

```
$(function() {
 var i = window.setInterval(function(){
    $('#Images').load('get_image.htm');
 },1000 );
});
```

You can stop the reloading anytime with

```
clearInterval(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

This would do it

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    $('#Images').load('get_image.htm'); // get_image.htm displays image
  },100 );
});
```

Using [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval) you can have a function repeated after the specified number of milliseconds (100 in this case)

Answer (score 1):

avoid to use strings inside setTimeout/Interval, just try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var div = $('#Images');
  setInterval(function() {
    div.load('get_image.htm'); // get_image.htm displays image
  }, 1000);
});
```

if you need to make a call every second, then delay has to be `1000` (and not 100, otherwise your server will receive 600 reqs/min instead of 60).

Also create an outer-scoped reference to the node  so you won't re-evaluate `$('#Images')` at every function call

Answer (score 0):

If you need every second, then use setInterval and 1000ms is 1 sec.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval('LoadImages',1000 );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout('LoadImages()',100 )` should be like `setTimeout(LoadImages,1000 );` for 1sec as `setTimeout` takes the interval param in `millisecond`. To execute it every one second you should use `setInterval` like `setInterval(LoadImages,1000)`. `setTiemout` will run it only once.

as `setTimeout` takes function reference where using `'LoadImages()'` will trigger `eval` and execute the function immediately and return null.

You should also use append instead of loading the image into that div again and again which will replace all previous ones. I am not sure if you intentionally want that.

```
$(function() {
 var i = window.setInterval(function(){
    $('#Images').load('get_image.htm');
 },1000 );
});
function LoadImages()
{
 $.get('get_image.htm',function(data){
    $('#Images').append(data);
 });
}
```